# (xcode) Arc Semantic issue - init methods must return a type related to the receiver type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't fix up that ARC Problem.

detail error message is " init methods must return a type related to the receiver type"

**@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *initURL;**

this code line has error issue.

i added .h and .m file.

please help me :)

xcode5, ios

```
//
//  MFTabBarController.h
//  ELandMobileFramework
//
//  Created by Kim DongGeun on 12. 2. 23..
//  Copyright (c) 2012년 purpleworks. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MFTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    NSString *initURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *initURL;

- (id)init;
- (void)initSelectedIndexWithInitURL:(NSString *)url;
//- (void)setInitURL:(NSString *)initURL;

@end






//
//  MFTabBarController.m
//  ELandMobileFramework
//
//  Created by Kim DongGeun on 12. 2. 23..
//  Copyright (c) 2012년 purpleworks. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MFTabBarController.h"

#import "MFSettingHelper.h"
#import "MFUrlRoute.h"
#import "MFUrlHelper.h"
#import "MFAppDelegate.h"

#import "MFAccountSqlite.h"

#import "MFRootViewController.h"
#import "MFSettingViewController.h"
#import "MFRootNavigationController.h"

@interface MFTabBarController()
- (void)initViewControllers;
@end

@implementation MFTabBarController
@synthesize initURL = _initURL;

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initViewControllers];
    }
    return self;
}

//-(id) initURL:(NSString *)initUrl
//{
//    if (self = [super init]) {
//        //do stuff
//        _initURL = (NSString *)init;
//        
//    }
//    return self;
//}

- (void)initViewControllers 
{
    // view controller array
    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    // root view nibname
    NSString *nibName = [MFSettingHelper getValue:@"RootViewClassName"];
    if([nibName isEqualToString:@"MFRootViewController"]) {
        nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ELandMobileFrameworkResource.bundle/%@", nibName];
    }
    /*
    // get menu list
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MFAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *menuEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MenuSection" 
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:menuEntity];
    NSMutableArray *menus = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
     */
    MFAccountSqlite *accountSqlite = [[MFAccountSqlite alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *menus = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[accountSqlite getMenuSections]];
    for (int i=0; i < [menus count]; i++) {
        MFMenuSectionModel *sectionModel = (MFMenuSectionModel *)[menus objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j=0; j <[[sectionModel menus] count]; j++) {
            MFMenuModel *menu = [[sectionModel menus] objectAtIndex:j];
            MFUrlRoute *route = [[MFUrlRoute alloc] initWithUrl:menu.url];

            if([route equal:@"webview" action:@"loadUrl"] == YES) {
                MFRootViewController *rootViewController = [[NSClassFromString([MFSettingHelper getValue:@"RootViewClassName"]) alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
                MFRootNavigationController *navigationController = [[MFRootNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
                [navigationController setOrientation:[MFSettingHelper getValue:@"Orientation" defaultValue:@"portrait"]];

                [tabViewControllers addObject:navigationController];
            }
        }
    }

    // setting view
    MFSettingViewController *settingViewController = [[MFSettingViewController alloc] init];
    MFRootNavigationController *navigationController = [[MFRootNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingViewController];
    [navigationController setOrientation:[MFSettingHelper getValue:@"Orientation" defaultValue:@"portrait"]];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:navigationController];

    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

    // update tab style
    int tabCount = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < [menus count]; i++) {
        MFMenuSectionModel *sectionModel = (MFMenuSectionModel *)[menus objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j=0; j <[[sectionModel menus] count]; j++) {
            MFMenuModel *menu = [[sectionModel menus] objectAtIndex:j];
            MFUrlRoute *route = [[MFUrlRoute alloc] initWithUrl:menu.url];

            if([route equal:@"webview" action:@"loadUrl"] == YES) {
                [[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabCount] tabBarItem] setTitle:menu.name];
                if([menu.icon hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
                    [[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabCount] tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:menu.icon]]]];
                } else {
                    [[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabCount] tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:menu.icon]];
                }

                [[[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabCount] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setDefaultURL:[MFUrlHelper getFullUrl:[route.params objectForKey:@"url"]]];
                [[[[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabCount] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:menu.name];
                if (![menu.badge isEqualToString:@""] && tabCount < 4) {
                    [[[[self tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:tabCount] setBadgeValue:menu.badge];
                }
                if ([menu.url isEqualToString:initURL]) {
                    [self setSelectedIndex:tabCount];
                }
                tabCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)initSelectedIndexWithInitURL:(NSString *)url 
{
    if (url) {
        [self setInitURL:url];
    }
    [self initViewControllers];
}

#pragma mark - navigationController Delegate
- (void)navigationController: (UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController: (UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated: (BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationBar* morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem* morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;
    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short answer:** to fix the error:

1) rename the property so it doesn't start with `init`.

2) Do the same for your method `(void)initSelectedIndexWithInitURL:(NSString *)url`. *(Update: @robmayoff says that that method does not cause an error. I'd rename it anyway, to ensure good style and to avoid any confusion.)*

**Explanation:**

The compiler tries to create a getter and setter for your property, like this:

```
- (void)setInitURL:(NSString *)initURL;
- (NSString *)initURL;
```

The 2nd method causes a problem. The compiler treats methods that start with `init` differently from any other methods. Such methods are supposed to initialize and return the `self` reference of the object they're called on (the receiver object). In this case though, it's just a getter returning a string. Hence the compiler error.

Comment: ARC keys off naming conventions, you must follow them. See [Programming With Objective-C Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)

Comment: It is not necessary to rename `initSelectedIndexWithInitURL:` (although it might be a good idea).  Methods that return `void` don't have to follow the convention for return values, because they return nothing.  The compiler doesn't complain about this method.  It is only necessary to rename `initURL`.

Comment: @robmayoff thanks for the clarification, that's good to know! I'll amend my answer.